# Less compact form

Tags: loops, dictionary, for-loop

```
def read_file(filename):
    trolls = dict()
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            for line in file:
                city, data = line.split(':')
                for i in data.split():
                trolls[city] = [int(_) for _ in data.split()]
    except OSError as error:
        print(f"Yeuch!: {error}")
    return trolls
```

How can I rewrite this line:

```
trolls[city] = [int(_) for _ in data.split()]
```

in a less compact way?

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines in your code

```py
for i in data.split(): 
    trolls[city] = [int(_) for _ in data.split()]
```

the `for` loop is uselessly repeating the work on the second line however many elements are in the list times, but the result is the same.

(in your code, the second line isn't indented but it should be, otherwise you'll just get a `SyntaxError`, so I assume it just didn't paste correctly and you have it indented)

I think you meant to do this

```py
if city not in trolls:
    trolls[city] = []
for i in data.split(): 
    trolls[city].append(int(i))
```

or simply delete the `for i in data.split():` line in your original code.